# Excel VBA code - Amend to pick up other tables in different page?

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

A quick question about the amending of a piece of code to pick up other web page table contents. I had some great guidance on here about how to pick up certain table contents based on the title and it works great - thanks again to ['QHarr'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6241235/qharr) who was so helpful.

The URL I was wanting the table details from was:

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/?p=AAPL

This is the piece of code which took the data I wanted:

```
Sub GetYahooInfo100()
Dim tickers(), ticker As Long, lastRow As Long, headers()
Dim wsSource As Worksheet, http As clsHTTP, html As HTMLDocument

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("100")
Set http = New clsHTTP

headers = Array("Ticker", "Previous Close", "Open", "Bid", "Ask", "Day's Range", "52 Week Range", "Volume", "Avg. Volume", "Market Cap", "Beta", "PE Ratio (TTM)", "EPS (TTM)", _
                "Earnings Date", "Forward Dividend & Yield", "Ex-Dividend Date", "1y Target Est")

With wsSource
    lastRow = GetLastRow(wsSource, 1)
    Select Case lastRow
    Case Is < 3
        Exit Sub
    Case 3
        ReDim tickers(1, 1): tickers(1, 1) = .Range("A3").Value
    Case Is > 3
        tickers = .Range("A3:A" & lastRow).Value
    End Select

    ReDim Results(0 To UBound(tickers, 1) - 1)
    Dim i As Long, endPoint As Long
    endPoint = UBound(headers)

    For ticker = LBound(tickers, 1) To UBound(tickers, 1)
        If Not IsEmpty(tickers(ticker, 1)) Then
            Set html = http.GetHTMLDoc("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & tickers(ticker, 1) & "/?p=" & tickers(ticker, 1))
            Results(ticker - 1) = http.GetInfo(html, endPoint)
            On Error Resume Next
            Set html = Nothing
        Else
            Results(ticker) = vbNullString
        End If
    Next

    .Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
    For i = LBound(Results) To UBound(Results)
        .Cells(3 + i, 2).Resize(1, endPoint - 1) = Results(i)
    Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

With a further piece below:

```
Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
With ws
    GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

End Function

Like I say one of the members on here was very helpful in identifying how to do that. I have tried in vein to amend the piece of code to pick up another set of data from the statistics page, as follows:

https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics?p=AAPL

but I must be missing something. Unless my references are incorrect for the tables then I'm at a loss. I am looking to see if I can capture all the data fields in each of the tables, not just one which is where I may be going wrong.

Was hoping someone may be able to assist.

With forward thanks.

Comment: What are you after from the new url? https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics?p=AAPL  All the tables?

Comment: All the tables would be amazing! If do’able. I’ve tried with different references using the original code but I’m missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetYahooInfo()
    Dim tickers(), ticker As Long, lastRow As Long, headers()
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, http As Object, html As New HTMLDocument
    headers = Array("Previous Close", "Open", "Bid", "Ask", "Day's Range", "52 Week Range", "Volume", "Avg. Volume", "Market Cap", _
                    "Beta", "PE Ratio (TTM)", "EPS (TTM)", "Earnings Date", "Forward Dividend & Yield", "Ex-Dividend Date", "1y Target Est", _
                    "Market Cap (intraday)", "Enterprise Value", "Trailing P/E", "Forward P/E", "PEG Ratio (5 yr expected)", "Price/Sales (ttm)", _
                    "Price/Book (mrq)", "Enterprise Value/Revenue", "Enterprise Value/EBITDA", "Fiscal Year Ends", "Most Recent Quarter (mrq)", _
                    "Profit Margin", "Operating Margin (ttm)", "Return on Assets (ttm)", "Return on Equity (ttm)", "Revenue (ttm)", "Revenue Per Share (ttm)", _
                    "Quarterly Revenue Growth (yoy)", "Gross Profit (ttm)", "EBITDA", "Net Income Avi to Common (ttm)", "Diluted EPS (ttm)", _
                    "Quarterly Earnings Growth (yoy)", "Total Cash (mrq)", "Total Cash Per Share (mrq)", "Total Debt (mrq)", _
                    "Total Debt/Equity (mrq)", "Current Ratio (mrq)", "Book Value Per Share (mrq)", "Operating Cash Flow (ttm)", _
                    "Levered Free Cash Flow (ttm)", "Beta", "52-Week Change", "S&P500 52-Week Change", "52 Week High", "52 Week Low", _
                    "50-Day Moving Average", "200-Day Moving Average", "Avg Vol (3 month)", "Avg Vol (10 day)", _
                    "Shares Outstanding", "Float", "% Held by Insiders", "% Held by Institutions", "Shares Short (Aug 31, 2018)", _
                    "Short Ratio (Aug 31, 2018)", "Short % of Float (Aug 31, 2018)", "Short % of Shares Outstanding (Aug 31, 2018)", _
                    "Shares Short (prior month Jul 31, 2018)", "Forward Annual Dividend Rate", "Forward Annual Dividend Yield", _
                    "Trailing Annual Dividend Rate", "Trailing Annual Dividend Yield", "5 Year Average Dividend Yield", "Payout Ratio", _
                    "Dividend Date", "Ex-Dividend Date", "Last Split Factor (new per old)", "Last Split Date")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<== Change as appropriate to sheet containing the tickers

    With wsSource
        lastRow = GetLastRow(wsSource, 1)
        Select Case lastRow
        Case Is < 3
            Exit Sub
        Case 3
            ReDim tickers(1, 1): tickers(1, 1) = .Range("A3").Value
        Case Is > 3
            tickers = .Range("A3:A" & lastRow).Value
        End Select

        Dim i As Long, sResponse As String
        Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

        For ticker = LBound(tickers, 1) To UBound(tickers, 1)
            With Worksheets("Sheet1")
                If Not IsEmpty(tickers(ticker, 1)) Then
                    With http
                        .Open "GET", "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & tickers(ticker, 1) & "/key-statistics?p=" & tickers(ticker, 1), False
                        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
                        .send
                        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
                    End With

                    sResponse = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))   
                    html.body.innerHTML = sResponse

                    Dim tables As Object, destLastRow As Long
                    Dim counter As Long: counter = 2

                    Set tables = html.querySelectorAll("tbody td")             
                    .Cells(2, 2).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers

                    For i = 1 To tables.Length - 1 Step 2
                        .Cells(ticker + 2, counter) = tables(i).innerText
                        If InStr(tables(i).innerText, "Last Split Date") > 0 Or InStr(tables(i + 1).innerText, "Last Split Date") > 0 Then
                            Exit For
                        End If
                        counter = counter + 1
                    Next
                    Set html = Nothing: Set tables = Nothing
                Else
                    .Cells(2 + ticker, 2) = "N/A"
                End If
            End With
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

---

**Sample results:**

[image]

Comment: Hey man - that's great! It creates a list in a column down from B3, unlike the original which populates the row 3 along from cell A3, then gets next value from A4 etcetera. Is that the intention with your code - or perhaps that's what I asked for!! I was looking for values for a list of tickers similar to the original, with values populating the corresponding row. If that is too much for all this info, I could create a different sheet for each and populate that accordingly? Is the previous method an option at all? Thank you.

Comment: 'A little tidier' looks great. Putting all the data on to another sheet. I have populated cells A3-A9 with tickers and sheet 2 is opulated with the data for all 6. 75 rows for each, 450 rows all told. Just need to either work out a way to isolate the data for each ticker, or maybe create a new sheet for each, with the ticker as the sheet name. It is very much what i used to use before Yahoo took away the previous method of gathering information.

Comment: I tried replacing the code and trying it against 6 tickers in column A. It places the headers in row 2, but fails in gathering the data across each ticker row for the ticker. Perhaps I am doing something wrong - am I to simply copy the code and voila? Thank you.

Comment: The six I am currently using as a test are:AAPL
AAT
AAV
AB
ABB
ABBV

Comment: I have yes - it's obviously something I'm doing as it's not populating the cells. I have the following References enabled - Visual Basic for Applications, MS Ex 16.0 Object Library, MS Office 16.0 Object Library, OLE Automation & MS HTML Object Library..

Comment: That works perfectly? I've saved it and it's saved as an Excel Binary Workbook as opposed to a Macro Enabled? Any reason that might be. My original file appears to be identical? Thanks again.

Comment: xlsb format are smaller so preferable to .xlsm. They both run macros. It was tested and ran fine. Be aware that if there is formatting for example left in the sheet, the end row may not be what you think it is and you will find the results much lower down the worksheet.

Comment: I edited a line in the above code to the following:  .Cells(ticker + 2, counter) = tables(i).innerText   to avoid problems with formatting interfering.

Comment: That’s really quite remarkable. Can’t thank you enough. Have a great day 

Comment: I am looking to get this workbook up and running again after 3 years of being concerned with other things. I've looked through the comments and even though I've managed to align to your guidance once again, I am struggling with the same problem I had previously. That being that when there is an error, or a stock is now not available, it doesn't jump to the next, but populates the blank cell. So when it has stopped running, data on the feed column ends up being longer in rows than the results column. Is there any updates that you could advise, otherwise I'll keep on with this method.